# Need to convert a sharepoint list field value from FieldValuesAsText to FieldValuesAsHtml in pnp-sp spfx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core, office-dev-pnp

I need lookupfield value,peoplepicker field value and enrich multiline text field value in one pnp-sp get call and display it in a table columnd so i used

```
let item: [] = await siteweb.lists.getByTitle(this.props.list).items.getById(propKey[this.props.propertybagid]).fieldValuesAsText.get();
```

to get all values here i didnt get enrich value so i used `FieldValueAsHtml` instead of `FieldValueAsText` and used

`<td><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.result1[mkey]}} /></td>`  in UI 
Here i didnt get lookup field value peoplepicker value as text form
so i used this code to convert the text value of MLT field to html like this

```
let arlink =this.state.result1[mkey].FieldValuesAsHtml;
```

please help me to solve

Comment: I don't think I understand what the question is.  From what you've written, it sounds like you've already solved the problem?

Comment: i need to get people picker field value and enrich MLT field value without loosing its html property and hiding html tag from single get call . Now people picker value contains html